# To remove special characters from data while moving data from mssql to mysql using pentaho data integration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde

In a Table data, I have to remove these  `[*,=,#,&,^,%]` from table data. I should not remove these

special characters  `[(,),/,.,@,',",:-,_,,\]` while moving data from `mssql` to `mysql` using `pentaho` data

integration

example:-

```
Gujarat is the countryÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â€ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â™s largest castor oil seed producing state. The m*ajor 

monthÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â€ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â™s
```

Comment: Can you use a `Sql Server` function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "User Defined Java Class" in Pentaho and write a regex expression with the replace function.

```
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException{
Object[] r = getRow();
if (r == null) {
    setOutputDone();
    return false;
}

if (first)
{
    first = false;
}

r = createOutputRow(r, 1);


if(get(Fields.In, "data").getString(r) != null) 
{
    String output= get(Fields.In, "data").getString(r);

    output= output.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s()/\\.@-_]+","");

    get(Fields.Out, "output").setValue(r, output);

}else {
    get(Fields.Out, "output").setValue(r, "");
}

putRow(data.outputRowMeta, r);

return true;
}
```

**data** is the input stream data and the cleaned output would be in "**output**" column. I have shared a sample code [here](https://github.com/rishuatgithub/Pentaho/tree/master/stackoverflow-pentaho-samples/RemoveSpecialCharacter_UDJC).

Hope this will solve your issue. :)

---

Modifying my earlier answer to include the full code. Having said this, i have also created a plugin recently to handle special characters. You can have a look at my blog site :

Blog link: https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/special-character-remover-clean-your-data-of-special-characters-pentaho-kettle-step-plugin/

Even though its only version 1.0.0, but you can have a try. It might also help ypu :)

Comment: I have used above statement as it is in User Defined Java Class iam getting error when testing the class like Line 1, Column 5: Identifier expected

Comment: @SRI i have modified the above answer to include the full code. also attached a sample code and a plugin link (blog link)... please check and see if it work !! Sorry for the delay in answering !!

Comment: Hi Rishu for above code output= output.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s()/\\.@-_]+","");.Here if i want to include :(colon) in the data like at 2:40 pm.In data it is coming at 240 pm . Here i want to see at 2:40 pm just to include : where i can include that

Comment: @SRI .. this is very basic stuff.. you just need to include the colon in your above regex.. try something [^a-zA-Z0-9\\s()/\\.:@-_]+ ... it will ignore the colon in the input steam.

Comment: thanks for u r reply. I dont want to ignore colon, i want include it

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regular expressions in the query you are using to retrieve the data? It will simplify your transformation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `Regex Evaluation` step or `String operations` step in Spoon[image]

Try them and if you still have problems comment below.